# Is "Englishnization" an acceptable term?

Tags: suffixes, morphology, neologisms

There's a company named Rakuten in Japan, which introduced "Englishnization" a couple of years ago. They adopted an internal policy where all the employees are expected to speak English as an official language. They coined this somewhat bold move as "Englishnization".

My question is whether this new term is acceptable or not. Some people say that the "n" in the middle is quite awkward, and it should have been "Englishization" (without *n*).

I understand that neither:

- Englishization
- Englishnization

is broadly accepted broadly. I am just wondering which makes more sense to coin as a new term. IMHO, the fact that Englishization has an [entry on Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Englishization) does not make this one more acceptable.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is already a word for converting something to English:

[Anglicization](http://i.word.com/idictionary/anglicization) /Anglicisation (AmE/BrE)

> 1 : to make English in quality or characteristics
>   2 : to adapt (a foreign word, name, or phrase) to English usage: as a : to alter to a characteristic English form, sound, or spelling b : to convert (a name) to its English equivalent <anglicize Juan as John>

It is almost only ever used to refer to the conversion of words or names, but it only needs a slight expansion of its meaning to cover the conversion of all business communication in a company.

A slight broadening of an existing word, in a way that is consistent with its history and existing usage, seems much preferable than coining a new, awkward phrase.

However! I'm not a Japanese speaker. What is *acceptable* depends on who has to accept it, so what word is acceptable for this idea is ultimately up to the people who use it. A Japanese speaker unfamiliar with the "English"/"Angle" transformation would probably find "Anglicization" unintuitive, and the *n* following the *sh* in "Englishnization" may well be roll off the tongue better for someone coming from a language in which a syllable-final *sh* doesn't exist and the only syllable-final consonant is *n*. As it is Japanese workers and companies who are the target demographic that is being sold on the concept, what a Western English speaker thinks *might* be irrelevant. Not knowing the agenda of Rakuten intimately, I can't be certain.

So, the short version:

- If you are asking what is most acceptable *to a Western* ear, either "Anglicization" or "Englishization" is what you want.
- If you are asking what is most acceptable *to a Japanese* ear, I cannot say for certain – but I would not be surprised if "Englishnization" becomes most accepted.
- If you are asking what is most acceptable *to both*, then you want to compromise and choose "Englishization", no *n*.

Comment: I'd upvote this but *Anglisization* with an S cannot be right (and the initial link demonstrates that). Full marks for consistency, but it's consistently wrong. *Anglicisation* or *Anglicization*, with a C.

Comment: But that’s a *different meaning*. The enterprise wasn’t anglicising Japanese words, nor were they necessarily anglicising themselves as a company (which would imply changing the company’s culture etc.). Rather, they were adopting English as an official language. I don’t think this action is comprised in the meanings of “anglicisation” but even if it were, there are sufficient causes for confusion to avoid using this word here.

Comment: ^ That is an excellent point. "Anglicization" means **taking something and making it more "English-y"**, but "English(n)ization" apparently means **adding English to the corporate culture**. The meanings are similar, but distinct enough that when discussing this particular phenomenon, _even in a western context_, it might be better to use "Englishization" to distinguish it from the different kinds of things associated with "Anglicization".

Comment: @Andrew TRiG graciously fixed that for me. I can only blame the infernally-tiny screen of my phone and being drowsy when I wrote it.

Comment: @Konrad Yes, it's a different meaning. That's why I wrote about the broadening of words, and "acceptability" rather than "correctness". If the asker wants *correctness* they'd be out of luck, as no such word exists. Fortunately, they asked about acceptability, which opens the door to the invention of new words or new meanings for existing ones.

Comment: I could have fixed it; but I wasn't sure you actually meant it. It's a material change. Anyway, +1 now.

Answer (score 12):

If one has to choose one of those two alternatives, *Englishization* is certainly better, as it is simply the root word, *English*, attached to the suffix, *-ization*.

There ARE examples of words in which a consonant is inserted between the rood word and *-ization*: for example, *drama* + *-ization* = *dramatization*. This is to break up the awkward string of vowels (or, in more linguistic terms, to make sure that every syllable has an onset) that would exist in **dramaization*. But there is no similar process that would motivate adding an extraneous *n* to *Englishization*.

Therefore, my answer is: if you need to attach *-ization* to *English*, the **only** possibility is *Englishization*. However, as you noted in your question, that word is also not widely used (a Google search for it turns up extremely few results). The "real word" for that concept is [anglicization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicisation).

Comment: There is, however, a process in Japanese that adds *n* in the coda in such cases.

Comment: What do you mean? The [n] in _Englishnization_ is in the onset: en-glish-ni-za-tion.

Comment: In Japanese the *sh* must be an onset, so an unwritten vowel + *n* gets added. It's comparable to the *e* that is added by Spanish speakers to word-initial *s*. It's not an English process of course, but that's undoubtedly why the word in question contains an *n* in what seems an awkward place to native English speakers. It's something more like en-ga-li-shen-i-ze-na-shen (IIRC) in Japanese syllabic structures.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense - the _sh_ is already the onset in the version without the _n_: en-gli-shi-za-tion (which would be something like イングリシゼション or _in-gu-ri-shi-ze-shon_ when converted to good Japanese syllable-structure). I'm not a Japanese speaker, really, but I've studied Japanese and Japanese linguistics, and I'm pretty sure there's no Japanese phonological reason to add an _n_ to that word. Adding an _n_ is basically creating a consonant cluster, after all, which is the opposite of what Japanese does to loanwords (it breaks up consonan t clusters).

Comment: But in any case, the original question was which makes more sense _in English_.

Comment: Yes, but we can't ignore culture (I addressed that in my answer). If we were talking about Indian English, the rules of Indian English would be what's relevant. Since we're talking about Japanese speakers speaking English… well, I suspect that, in a similar way, it's not so cut and dried. I'm not certain of the process (I'm guessing wildly at what that darned *n* is there for), but there's my hypothesis. I did make that a little less central to my answer.

Comment: Although I can't explain the linguistical/phonetical dynamics at work here, Englishnization(with n) sounds much better to my ear as a native Japanese speaker. I guess this is because we have so many loanwords from English that end with -nization. But, yes, my question was which sounds better for English speakers, not Japanese. It was quite interesting and also nice that you all should have considered how Japanese native speakers might feel.

Comment: FWIW, my own guess as to why the _n_ is in there is that because there are many common words in English that end in the string <nization>, such as _organization_ or _immunization_, so Japanese speakers looking to coin a new word mistakenly analyzed _*-nization_ as the productive suffix when it's really _-ization_. So it isn't a question of inserting an _n_ into _English_ + _-ization_, but rather of just forming a word from _English_ + _-nization_.

Comment: That does seem more likely on further thought, as it's a hypothesis with fewer "moving parts" than mine.

Comment: @knsmr: To be blunt, as a native English speaker, *Englishnization* is simply ridiculous. It's not even worth considering, if you truly want to target an English ear. I trust your Japanese ear, and I have every confidence that *Englishnization* sounds better (or at least just as good) to native Japanese speakers. But using this term as the name of a program to promote English is... well, either humorous or embarrassing, depending on your point of view.

Answer (score 8):

I think [anglification](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anglification) rolls off the tongue rather nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would go with either,

- Englishization.
- Englishinization.

Adding the extra vowel sound before the 'n' makes it sound better.

Here's a [list](http://www.wordbyletter.com/suffixes/words_finishing_with_zation.php) of words ending with 'zation', notice that most of the words ending in 'nization' have a vowel before the 'n.'

Of the two, I think the first one looks better in a written text, but I think the second one sounds better when spoken aloud.

Comment: "Nization" is not a thing. The n or even niz is already part of the words which seem to end in nization. "Tion" is the real suffix here breaking the word at nization is wrong.